# Setting initial values for pitch and roll for MPU6050 DMP processing

Tags: mpu6050, imu, dmp

I want to handle case when my MPU6050 is disconnected and reset. Unfortunately, after reinit MPU6050 shows pitch and roll values as 0 and stabilizes after ~1-2s with right values. I would like to hint DMP by writing last read values before reset. Is it any interface for it?
Btw, no matter I configure LPF with value 5 or 188 - 'issue' still exists.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Try logging the 16 bytes of memory beginning at `D_0_192` (defined in `inv_mpu_dmp_motion_driver.c` of `motion_driver_6.12`).

```c
unsigned short buf[16];
mpu_read_mem(D_0_192, 16, buf);
// your chosen method of logging this buffer
```

Mine looked like this shortly after `mpu_set_dmp_state(1)`:

```
3fffdfeb 003eb3b6 000d2278 00002f3c
```

and like this after stabilizing for 15 seconds:

```
1e246556 386e559d 01b407b2 004d6ad9
```

If my MPU6050-using device starts upside-down, it takes about this long for the readings to stabilize.

After the readings have stabilized, record the value as a constant and write it back to the same location when DMP setup happens:

```c
mpu_write_mem(D_0_192, 16, buf);
```

## Method

I logged the contents of some of the DMP's mentioned but unreferenced/undocumented registers in `inv_mpu_dmp_motion_driver.c` figuring that they probably expose this part of DMP state somewhere. I did this after a call to `mpu_set_dmp_state(1)`.

I found a number of values that change while the DMP is running.  `D_0_192`, which I believe to be the internal state corresponding to attitude was identifiable by its sluggish relaxation time.   I haven't taken the time to interpret the contents.  I have only copied the buffer and observed the intended result -- that the contents of the DMP fifo begin at the recorded attitude.

## Disclaimer

This is undocumented, potentially very wrong, and certainly brittle (untested on anything other than the DMP firmware blob included in `motion_driver_6.12`).  Use at your own risk.